# Show that if $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n > 0$ and $x_1 \cdot x_2 \cdot ... \cdot x_n = 1$ then $x_1 + x_2 + ... x_n \ge n$

Tags: induction

I have to show that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, n \ge 2$ if we have

$$x_1, x_2, ... x_n > 0$$

and

$$x_1 \cdot x_2 \cdot ... \cdot x_n = 1$$

then it is true that

$$x_1 + x_2 + ... x_n \ge n$$

How can I prove this? The textbook recommends using induction, but after trying it, I didn't get anywhere.

Comment: Maybe the [AM-GM Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means) is an easier way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid A.M. - G.M. inequality you can prove it by induction as follows.

Suppose the result is true for $n$. Consider positive numbers  $x_1,x_2,...,x_n,x_{n+1}$ whose product is $1$.

Let $y_i=x_i$ for $i <n$ and $y_n=x_nx_{n+1}$. Then $y_i$'s are positive and their product is $1$. By induction hypothesis we get $y_1+y_2+...+y_n\geq n$. Now $$x_1+x_2+...+x_n+x_{n+1}= y_1+y_2+..+y_n+x_{n+1} -x_nx_{n+1}$$ $$ \geq n +x_n+x_{n+1}-x_n+x_{n+1}$$ $$ \geq n+1$$ because $((1-t)(1-s) \leq 1$, so $t+s=ts \geq ts$ for $0,\leq t,s \leq 1$. [Take $t-x_n,s=x_{n+1}$].

Prof using AM -GM inequality: $\frac {x_1+x_2+...+x_n} n \geq (x_1x_2...x_n)^{1/n}=1^{1/n}=1$ so $x_1+x_2+...+x_n \geq 1$.

Comment: What if I wouldn't be required to avoid the A.M. - G.M. inequality? How would I use it here?

Comment: @user1502 I have added a second proof .